# Unable to use paging despite enabling paging

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, paging

I'm trying to allow paging for my gridview. I have allowpaging at my gridview and also added pagesize. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I researched and i have seen people not requiring to add any codes.

This is my source code for my gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="GVVerify" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" BackColor="#CCCCCC" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="3px" CellPadding="4" CellSpacing="2" CssClass="gridviewadminverify" ForeColor="Black" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GVVerify_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="100%">
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="White" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#808080" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#383838" />
            </asp:GridView>
```

This is how i connect my SQL via databinding which is different from using datasource.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source = localhost; Initial Catalog = project; Integrated Security= SSPI";
conn.Open();

DataSet ds = new DataSet();

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT policeid as [Police ID], password as [Password], email as [Email], nric as [NRIC], fullname as [Full Name], contact as [Contact], address as [Address], location as [Location] From LoginRegisterPolice where pending='pending'", conn);
da.Fill(ds);

GVVerify.DataSource = ds;           
GVVerify.DataBind();
conn.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using PageIndexChanging event and you have to bind [PageIndexChanging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.pageindexchanging.aspx) event and rebind your grid using current page.

**Html**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GVVerify" runat="server"  OnPageIndexChanging="GridViewPageEventHandler" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" BackColor="#CCCCCC" 
BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="3px" CellPadding="4" CellSpacing="2" 
CssClass="gridviewadminverify" ForeColor="Black" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GVVerify_SelectedIndexChanged" 
Width="100%">
```

**Code behind**

```
protected void grdView_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GVVerify.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    GVVerify.DataSource = GetGridData();
    GVVerify.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the PageIndexChanging event of the gridview.

for example:

```
protected void GVVerify_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        bindGrid();
        GVVerify.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        GVVerify.DataBind();
    }
```

where bindGrid method will contain the code for binding the grid.
For Example

```
private void bindGrid()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source = localhost; Initial Catalog = project; Integrated Security= SSPI";
        conn.Open();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT policeid as [Police ID], password as [Password], email as [Email], nric as [NRIC], fullname as [Full Name], contact as [Contact], address as [Address], location as [Location] From LoginRegisterPolice where pending='pending'", conn);
        da.Fill(ds);

       GVVerify.DataSource = ds;           
       GVVerify.DataBind();
       conn.Close();
    }
```